# Would schema issues prevent SelectNodes() from finding a node?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, schema

I have some very basic XML:

```
<ReconnectResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1">    
    <ErrorMessage/>    
    <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>    
    <ServerTime>2012-01-04T19:21:21.0782072Z</ServerTime>    
    <OAuthToken>redacted</OAuthToken>    
    <OAuthTokenSecret>redacted</OAuthTokenSecret>
</ReconnectResponse>
```

Simple, right?

So when I want to get the value for `ErrorCode`, my experience with XPath tells me to try `/ReconnectResponse/ErrorCode/text()`. This works in Notepad++ equipped with the XML Tools plugin, so lets try it in C#:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
var namespaceMan = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(@"/ReconnectResponse/ErrorCode", namespaceMan).InnerText);
```

I get an exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Which smells like a problem finding the specified node. Given how simple the XML is though, I'm struggling to work out what's going wrong.

On a whim, I plopped the XML into [XMLQuire](http://qutoric.com/xmlquire/). This gives XSD schema errors for each element type, like this:

> Could not find schema information for the element 'http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1:ReconnectResponse'.

So, my question is whether or not the schema errors could be causing `SelectSingleNode()` to miss my nodes? Secondary question: how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've ignored the namespace of your elements, which in this case is `http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1`. This is defined by the `xmlns=".."` attribute in the root element, and all child elements inherit this.

You need to add this namespace to the namespace manager with a prefix:

```
namespaceMan.AddNamespace("api", "http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1");
```

And use this prefix in your query:

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(@"/api:ReconnectResponse/api:ErrorCode", namespaceMan).InnerText;
```

As an aside, LINQ to XML is a far cleaner API than `XmlDocument` and offers much nicer query language than XPath. This code will get you the error code as an integer:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

XNamespace api = "http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1";

var errorCode = (int) doc.Descendants(api + "ErrorCode").Single();
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't spot LINQ to XML - clearly the way to go!